# Groupby function being deprecated

Tags: pandas

I'm a meteorologist and use Pandas extensively. When I was writing a script earlier, I got a warning that groupby is being deprecated in future versions of Pandas. I'm wondering what I can use in place of it. Thanks.

Comment: WHAT!! groupby is not being deprecated.

Comment: You probably misunderstood the error message, can you provide a reproducible example and the complete error traceback?

Comment: Just got it again. Maybe I misunderstood. Here's the error I got.

Dropping invalid columns in DataFrameGroupBy.max is deprecated. In a future version, a TypeError will be raised. Before calling .max, select only columns which should be valid for the function.

Comment: OK, that doesn't mean **at all**, that `groupby` is deprecated, just that if you have columns on which `max` cannot be used (objects for example), you should first filter them out.

Comment: I'm sorry; I'm a meteorologist by profession so this is still relatively new to me. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @David no worries, just be relieved `groupby` is here to stay ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is not deprecated (yet) and will (never) be I guess.

The last two major deprecated methods announced by the team Pandas was in [January 22, 2022 (version 1.4.0)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.3.5.html). The deprecations are :

1. `Int64Index`, `UInt64Index` & `Float64Index`
2. `DataFrame.append` and `Series.append`

When a Pandas method is deprecated, a warning is put in the official documentation, like for [`pandas.DataFrame.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas.DataFrame.append).

[image]